# Load Unity WebGL in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, unity-webgl

I'm a total neewbie in Web and Unity. What i'm trying to do is to run my Unity WebGL build inside my Flask server.

Here is my folder hierarchy:

```
web\
    templates\
        Build\
            UnityLoader.js
            WebBuild.json
        TemplateData\
            style.css
            TemplateData.js
        index.html
    app.py
```

`app.py` has 3 roots, to load all my `js` files asked by `index.html`:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/templates')
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/templates/Build/<path:path>')
def send_Buildjs(path):
    return send_from_directory('templates/Build', path)

@app.route('/templates/TemplateData/<path:path>')
def send_Templatejs(path):
    return send_from_directory('templates/TemplateData', path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=4555, debug=True)
```

`index.html` is the default generated file by Unity for WebGL application with some slight modifications:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | VisualNN</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='TemplateData/favicon.ico') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='TemplateData/style.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='TemplateData/UnityProgress.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='Build/UnityLoader.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
    var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "{{ url_for('static', filename='Build/WebBuild.json') }}", {onProgress: UnityProgress});

    </script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="webgl-content">
      <div id="unityContainer" style="width: 960px; height: 600px"></div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="webgl-logo"></div>
            <div class="fullscreen" onclick="unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1)"></div>
        <div class="title">VisualNN</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my Firefox browser icon is loaded, all `js` files are loaded too. I get 202 and 304 response messages for icons and `js` files.
But the unity game is not loading, no box just empty. Nothing is showing in the Firefox console.
I'm guessing that `Build/WebBuild.json` is not loading? As anyone has an idea what is the problem?

*EDIT*

Some extra info while I load the page from the Flask Server console:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2019 18:34:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2019 18:34:55] "GET /templates/TemplateData/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2019 18:34:55] "GET /templates/TemplateData/UnityProgress.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2019 18:34:55] "GET /templates/Build/UnityLoader.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2019 18:34:55] "GET /templates/TemplateData/webgl-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2019 18:34:55] "GET /templates/TemplateData/fullscreen.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a most simple solution, you just have to change your static folder and template folder paths on your app.py, here is an example:

```
`app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="./", template_folder="./")

 @app.route('/')
 def home():
    return render_template("index.html"), 200





 if __name__ == "__main__":
     port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
     app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port = port)`
```

With this you don't need to change anything on your index.html everytime you do a release.
P.D: You can hardcode any path you want, not just static folder, in my case it is my root project

[image]